# Lagrange's 4 square theorem: are there finite integers which require 4 non-zero squares in a unique way?

Tags: number-theory, sums-of-squares

I'm just reading about Lagrange's 4-square theorem, and realising that many integers can be expressed as the sum of 3 or fewer non-zero squares (eg 6=4+1+1). Legendre's 3-square theorem states that all numbers which cannot be expressed as the sum of 3 squares are of the from $4^k(8m+7)$, for integer k and m. Some integers are of this form, and thus require 4 squares but can have the sum done in multiple ways (eg 28=25+1+1+1=16+4+4+4).

This left me wondering: what is the set of integers which cannot be expressed as the sum of 3 squares, and have only one way to be expressed as the sum of 4 squares?

Suppose, in the above expression, we let k=0. We are now investigating numbers of the form $8m+7$.

The first several terms in this sequence have a unique summing, but then many other terms have several ways to be expressed as the sum of 4 squares:

7 = 4+1+1+1

15 = 9+4+1+1

23 = 9+9+4+1

31 = 25+4+1+1 = 9+9+9+4

39 = 36+1+1+1 = 25+9+4+1

When $k=1$, most terms seem to have multiple ways to express as the sum of 4 squares.

28 = 25+1+1+1 = 16+4+4+4

60 = 49+9+1+1 = 36+16+4+4

92 = 81+9+1+1 = 49+25+9+9

In general, the larger the number, the more likely there is to be multiple ways of expressing it as the sum of 4 squares.

Thus my question: ***Are there only finite integers which require 4 squares, and can only be expressed as the sum of 4 squares in a unique way?***

Is 23 the largest such number? Or what other numbers are there with this property?

Comment: http://oeis.org/A243582 says there are only seven numbers that cannot be expressed as the sum of four distinct squares:  7, 15, 23, 31, 47, 55, 103

Comment: Ok thanks that's also interesting but a different question to what I'm asking. It is possible that there is an integer which can be expressed as the sum of four distinct squares (hence does not appear in A243582) yet only in a unique way.

Comment: Yes, I found it because I was looking for a sequence of the numbers you are after, but didn't find it.  I just searched for 7,15,23 square and found this.